# Get base url in custom not.html.twig in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I made a custom node to show content type, say: node--blog.html.twig. Now I want to call base URL, but unable to do so. I tried code like below, but nothing worked:

```
<a href="{{ base_path }}">Read More</a>
<a href="{{ request.getBaseURL() }}">Apply</a>
<a href="<?php echo $GLOBALS['base_url'];?>">Apply</a>
```

How can I get base URL? I think there must be some variable like Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following to your .theme file:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['someVarName'] = $GLOBALS['base_url'];
}
```

And then access it in your node template like this:

```
{{ someVarName }}
```

Answer (score 0):

just in your template in `YOUR_THEME.theme`, add the following snippet.

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['base_path'] =base_path();
}
```